# Are there any cheap 1:25K electronic maps for the UK or Europe?

Tags: gear, maps, gps, uk

I have looked at offerings from MemoryMap and Anquet, but once you scale beyond a small area they become prohibitively expensive.

Comment: For what kind of device?

Comment: IIRC - MemoryMap and Anquet are PC/CD-ROM based maps... my question is: for what purpose?

Comment: I think this may be `too localized` and `off-topic` as it is a shopping question asking for recommendation of software.

Comment: You can ask for advice in choosing a map, or help in comparing choices... But "cheap" is relative, and tends to change quickly over time.

Comment: "Europe" is too localised?

Comment: @ChrisBallard I agree. The concencus here (http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/64/are-there-any-cheap-125k-electronic-maps-for-the-uk-or-europe) was that this question was ok, so respecting that I think it should be reopened unless someone comes up with a good reason otherwise.

Comment: @Shog9 It's not too localized; if the problem is the shopping aspect, it should be reopened and re-closed as off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, @Kevin, not sure what I was thinking there. Chris, right now this suffers not just from being a "shopping" question (as I said, asking for advice in choosing or comparing choices tends to work better on SE than straight-up "give me products"), but as the answer illustrates it's not really clear what you mean by "cheap" or "prohibitively expensive". If you outline what you're looking for and how what you've found has fallen short, others might be better equipped to provide you with advice on where to look.

Comment: OK thanks everyone. It seemed a pretty relevant question to me as an avid hiker, but I'll see if I can find the answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what area specifically you're looking at, or what your budget is - but Anquet seems to do a number of electronic copies of standard OS maps for prices I wouldn't consider unreasonable [here](http://www.anquet.com/Series/OS_1!25,000_Explorers.html).

Of course, if you mean the whole of the UK / Europe then the cost will be high, but I don't think there's really much getting around that. It unfortunately seems to be the case that if you want this level of detail, you have to pay for it! Who knows, in the future perhaps prices will come down somewhat.