# What free/open source maps can I put on my Garmin etrex vista HCX for walking in southern spain?

Tags: maps, gps, spain

Are there any maps available that would be useful for walking off-road in southern spain that I can use with my Garmin  etrex vista HCX?

Comment: I'm going to edit this question so that it isn't so specific to your trip. The purpose of stackexchange isn't really to provide an answer for use by the person posing the question, it's to collect questions and answers that will be useful to other people.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3865/gps-topo-map-downloads?rq=1 http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/64/are-there-any-cheap-125k-electronic-maps-for-the-uk-or-europe?rq=1 http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/704/looking-for-a-topographical-map-resource?rq=1

Comment: @BenCrowell: I don't think this is a correct edit as it completely change the question. Instead the question should be appropriately tagged with the graphical region.

Comment: @ppl: I would add [tag:garmin] tag to distinguish between specific types of GPS devices.

Comment: Do you have to use Garmin? If you have a phone with google maps you can use that internationally. GPS isn't using data and if you download the maps you can save it to your device and not worry about data at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would consider using [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) as they are [available for garmin devices](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Map_On_Garmin/Download).

Answer (score 2):

To add to ppl's reply, [Free maps for Garmin brand GPS devices](http://garmin.openstreetmap.nl/)

And [Ibycus Topo](http://www.ibycus.com/ibycustopo/)

And [GpsFileDepot](http://gpsfiledepot.com).

And there's probably more that could be added.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to Openstreetmap, I recommend [Opentopomap](http://garmin.opentopomap.org/).  It has the same trail data as Openstreetmap, but adds contour lines, which can be quite handy when hiking.

However, I recommend to never hike on a GPS alone.  Bring a paper map from the Spanish IGN.  You'll get more overview, and a GPS can break or run out of battery.